# Adding a label feature using tensorflow slim

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm using [slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim) to convert data into TF-Record format and looking at [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist.py), where the MNIST data-set is being converted.

On lines `127` to `128`, the image `png_string` is assigned a label, `labels[j]`.

```
example = dataset_utils.image_to_tfexample(png_string, 'png'.encode(), _IMAGE_SIZE, _IMAGE_SIZE, labels[j])
```

I would like to add another label, but as I look to the [`dataset_utils`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/dataset_utils.py) file and the `image_to_tfexample` function, I see:

```
    def image_to_tfexample(image_data, image_format, height, width, class_id):
  return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/encoded': bytes_feature(image_data),
      'image/format': bytes_feature(image_format),
      'image/class/label': int64_feature(class_id),
      'image/height': int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': int64_feature(width),
  }))
```

And it seems like I would have to edit this function to add another label (add another line of `image/class/label': int64_feature(class_id)`?)

I'm not entirely sure of how to add another label on which I'd like to train my neural network (maybe I'd just have to create another `image_to_tfexample()` with the same image but a different label?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it similar to the one you have already declared:

```
    def image_to_tfexample(image_data, image_format, height, width, class_id, label):
       return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
          'image/encoded': bytes_feature(image_data),
           'image/format': bytes_feature(image_format),
           'image/class/label': int64_feature(class_id),
           'image/label':int64_feature(label)
           'image/height': int64_feature(height),
           'image/width': int64_feature(width),
     }))
```

Remove the features you are not using, it will unnecessary increase your `tfrecords` size.

Comment: So, the class_id was the original label variable (that's what labels[j] stands in for in the example). Why did you remove the "class" part from "image/class/label" when you added label as another variable? Do you know what these "image/class/label" or "image/height" mean as a Features object?

Comment: Your question was to how to add a `new label` to the above `proto`. I didn't remove anything, added a new feature with a new key.   You can add whatever you like by : `'Key': int64_feature(value). When you are reading the records you will retrieve the value using `key`.  So the keys needed to be different.